# mean of the probability activation for each day of a week with python

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe df with this structure :

```
TIMESTAMP probab-activ1  probab-activ3  probab-activ5    
2015-07-31 23:00:00 90.0 90.0 90.0 
2015-07-31 23:10:00 0.0 0.0 0.0 
2015-07-31 23:20:00 0.0 0.0 0.0 
2015-07-31 23:30:00 0.0 0.0 0.0 
2015-07-31 23:40:00 0.0 0.0 0.0
...
2015-10-31 23:20:00 0.0 0.0 0.0 
2015-10-31 23:30:00 0.0 0.0 0.0 
2015-10-31 23:40:00 0.0 0.0 0.0
```

I need to calculate for each day of the week (monday , tuesday ,.., sunday) the mean of the probability (probab-activ1, probab-activ3 and probab-activ5) durant the 2 last months.

Any idea to solve this problem?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please show us what you have tried

Comment: get the last number of the first column with `a.split('-')[2]` and calculate its mod with 7. If it is let's say 1 it's a e.g., Monday. Every possible outcome (0-6) corresponds to a day of the week. Map them with a dict. Collect all 'Mondays' and divide by their number of instances

Comment: @Arman thank you for your reply. I didn't make a try , i am just looking for an idea to extract day (monday , ..) from the timestamp. It seems a liitle bit complicated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `datetime` module and convert your timestamp to a format that is useful for your purpose. For example, you could do:

```
import datetime

timestamp = '2015-07-31 23:00:00'
day_of_week = datetime.datetime.strptime(timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').strftime('%a')

day_of_week
'Fri'
```

Comment: thank you for your reply but in my case, I have the column timestamp as  a 38840 non-null object and not a string, so strptime function cannot not work